# Using Indian rupee symbol from tfrupee in math mode

Tags: math-mode, fonts, symbols

I can't seem to use the rupee symbol using package tfrupee if I am in math mode. The output produces a vertical line instead of the symbol. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tfrupee}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Current Fuel Consumption ($\frac{Volume}{Time}$)  \& Cost of Fuel ($\frac{\rupee}{Volume}$)
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output from above]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you tried `\text{\rupee}`?

Comment: `\text` is from the `amsmath` package: `\usepackage{amsmath}... \begin{document}.... $...\frac{\text{\rupee}}...$`

Comment: *Please* also the other words as text: `$\frac{\text{Volume}}{\text{Time}}$` and `$\frac{\text{\rupee}}{\text{Volume}}$`

Answer (score 3):

This solution checks, whether in math mode or not and selects the matching command automatically.

[image: rupee]

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tfrupee}

\let\orupee\rupee
\def\rupee{\ifmmode\text{\orupee}\else\orupee\fi}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item a \rupee
    \item Current Fuel Consumption ($\frac{Volume}{Time}$)  \& Cost of Fuel ($\frac{\rupee}{Volume}$)
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```